# how to learn time of remote linux machine

Tags: date, remote, time

We have a lot of Linux machines. We need their time values and I do not know how to learn time of remote linux machine?

Any one know a command or script for this issue?

Comment: Did you even try to look this up yourself? https://is.gd/hPVqP9

Comment: Why don't you use NTP to keep all clock synchronized?

Comment: of course yes but our linux machines not support rsh or ssh. And we want this information from a windows machine.

Comment: we use the NTP also want know how to learn time of remote linux machines

Comment: A full blown solution could be: configuring NTP on all those linux machines and then setup Nagios for monitoring.

Comment: What accuracy is sufficient?

Answer (score 1):

What accuracy is sufficient?

You could enable the `daytime` or `time` service and get the time either as text or as 4 bytes representing seconds since the beginning of 1900.

Here is a simple example in `perl` that will allow you to confirm that the [RFC 868 time service](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc868.txt) is running on the target server:

```
nc {target_server} time |
    perl -e 'sysread(STDIN,$l,4) and print unpack("N",$l) - 2_208_988_800,"\n"'
1476267393
```

The `perl` script reads four bytes, per [RFC 868](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc868.txt), which represents seconds since midnight 1st January 1900. It converts that to seconds since 1st January 1970 (*the epoch*) for Linux/UNIX systems to handle. (A Windows application might prefer the 1900 based value.)

You can then convert that number back to a readable date like this:

```
date --date @1476267393
Wed 12 Oct 11:16:33 BST 2016
```

Or as already suggested you could go the full way and use NTP. There are myriad pages on setting up NTP so I'll not duplicate those here.